# How to move and rotate a bitmap in a canvas using a matrix in android/java?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rotation, android-canvas

I am trying to create an animation where a bitmap is supposed to fall from top of the screen to the bottom while rotating around itself.

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
    posY[i]+=10;
    matrix[i].setTranslate(posX[i],posY[i]);
    matrix[i].postRotate(10);
    c.drawBitmap(lethal[i],matrix[i],null);

    if(posY[i]>screenY){
        posY[i] =(float) (Math.random() * screenY *-3);
        posX[i] = (float) (Math.random() * screenX);
    }
}
```

However, when i do this, the matrix starts to move other directions. I want the movement to be straight from top to bottom, but image itself rotate.

Comment: try to postRotate with a pivot point

Comment: which pivot poıint should i take in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late, but for others attempting the same thing, you can try creating a new matrix on each iteration of the View draw function. After creating a new matrix inside the loop, you can apply the transformations in the correct order.

```
Matrix myMatrix;
int translateX = 0;
int translateY = 0;
int rotation = 0;
// Below are variables for the rotation's pivot point.
// The values I gave can pivot around the center of a 200x200 bitmap.
int rotationCenterX = 100;
int rotationCenterY = 100;

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
    myMatrix = new Matrix();
    myMatrix.postRotate(rotation, rotationCenterX, rotationCenterY);
    myMatrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);

    // apply this matrix to the bitmap
    c.drawBitmap(<your bitmap here>, myMatrix, new Paint());

    // put this on a loop (just for animation)
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    invalidate();
}
```

Its a little inefficient, but I'm having trouble finding a simpler way to do the same.

Comment: If you're creating a new object on every onDraw() call, you'll end up with a lot of objects for garbage collection -> not really good idea.

Comment: @theamateur this is a bad idea i recommend value animator for this.